# $f: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ where $f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$ open and closed mapping?

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $f: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ where $f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$ is both an open and closed mapping, or provide counter-examples if one or both are not true.

Well, my hypothesis is that they are both true, that open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ map to open sets, and closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ map to closed sets. I could not think of any counter-examples since yesterday, unless I am missing something.

Anyway, it is a trivial case if $f(X) = S^1$ since $S^1$ is both and open and closed in itself.

I feel intuitively that an open or closed interval will map to an open or closed arc segment on the given unit circle, respectively. But I don't know how to write this in mathematical form. Or this not true in general?

Comment: This map is indeed an open and closed mapping.

Comment: Consider the set $f(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I take that back. $f$ is an open mapping, but not a closed mapping.

Comment: If $A$ is closed _and bounded_, then $f(A)$ is, indeed, closed. All counterexamples are unbounded.

Comment: @JHance isn't the image of $f(\mathbb{Z})$ a closed set of isolated points on the unit circle?

Comment: @morphic: No, the set will be isolated points, but there will be a cluster around the point $(1,0)$ (which is mapped to only by irrational elements), for example.

Comment: @Clayton If the set is isolated points, then isn't this set closed? Also I can't see why the isolated points aren't distributed evenly around the circle (i.e. why is there a cluster around $(1,0) \in S^1$)?

Comment: $f(\Bbb{Z})$ is a dense subset of $S^1$ (follows from Dirichlet/Kronecker density theorem and irrationality of $\pi$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok I think that is too complicated for me to understand, never mind trying to explain $f(\mathbb{Z})$ to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This map is not closed. Consider for example $F = \{2n\pi + \frac 1n: n = 1,2,\ldots\}$. It is open though. To prove it note that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals. Since an open interval is mapped onto an open arc (which is open if we think about $S_1$ with arc metric) or the whole circle, the image is a union of open sets which is open.

Comment: How do I prove that an open interval is mapped onto an open arc?

Comment: In order to prove that it's an arc you can use the fact that the continuous image of a connected set is connected (as long as we believe that arcs are the only connected subsets of $S_1$). Now, we can check the cases where the arc is closed, open, or mixed to reach the conclusion. The other way to prove it would be by using the continuity of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ to find a ball contained in the image for every its point - here we don't really need the fact that the image is an arc.

Comment: I'm not sure why f(F) is not closed?

Comment: $F$ is a sequence of points with the limit $(1,0)$. Then it is not closed, because $(1,0) \notin F$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is indeed open.

To show that $f$ is open, it is sufficient to show that $f$ takes open intervals to open sets (since the open intervals form a topological basis).

In order to show that an open arc is an open set, it suffices to show that there is a continuous onto map from the arc to an open interval.

Comment: An open surjection need not be closed, and in fact $f$ is not closed.

Comment: The only way a continuous surjection could show the arc is open is if you use something like invariance of domain, which is ridiculous. Are you familiar with the subspace topology?

Comment: @MattSamuel I am, if that will make things easier to explain

Comment: Take the endpoints of the arc. Any circle that passes through those endpoints that is not the circle itself does not intersect the circle in any other point (a circle is determined by three points). Take an open disc bounded by such a circle; this is open in the plane and its intersection with the circle is the open arc, so the arc is open.

Comment: To make it completely sound you'd have to figure out exactly why the intersection is the arc. You may have to bound the radius (can two circles be  tangent at two points? I don't know.). You also have to restrict it to the smaller arc. In any case, I'm sure it can be made to work. The moral of the story is that math is hard.

Comment: Ah! Easy. You can just insist that they aren't tangent. Then it works. Anyway, I'll stop posting tons of comments now.

Comment: @MattSamuel No, your comments are helping me tons and I really need the help

Comment: @morphic though it's good to know how to prove it, I'm sure if this is an assignment you can likely get away with assuming open arcs are open.

Comment: @MattSamuel The main issue I have is proving that open intervals map to open arcs

Comment: Arcs are parameterized by angles. An open arc is all points that are at angles strictly in between two angles. That help?

Comment: $f(]-3\pi,3\pi[)$ seems very closed to me.

Comment: Any two angles that differ by less than $2\pi$. Better?

Comment: In any case, it's closed, but it's also open.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks. I'm now trying to think of an "easy" closed set that maps to a set that's not closed with this function.

Comment: The other answer gives a pretty good example.

Comment: @MattSamuel I agree that the given set $F$ in that example is a closed set consisting of isolated points, but I fail to see that the image is not closed

Comment: The image is a sequence that has $(1,0)$ as a limit point but does not contain it.

Comment: @MattSamuel Is there a geometric explanation of why the $2n\pi$ constant must be added to every $\frac{1}{n}$ in order for this to work? i.e. why not just $\frac{1}{n}$ without the $+ 2n\pi$. Since it looks like something like $\cos (2n\pi + 1) = \cos (1)$ anyway

Comment: It's the domain you want to look at for the explanation. You want a sequence that has that limit point. You could just use an infinite sequence of points near 0 or any multiple of $2\pi$ to accomplish this, but then it wouldn't be closed because it would have a limit point. If we stretch it out though it has no limit points, is closed, and has the same image.